# Installing ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn

Tags: ros, installation, ros-indigo, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

while trying to install ROS Indigo on the newest distribution Ubuntu 14.10

```
       sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop
```

I got following error:

```
       The following packages have unmet dependencies:
       ros-indigo-desktop : 
                  Depends: ros-indigo-robot but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ros-indigo-rqt-robot-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ros-indigo-visualization-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ros-indigo-viz but it is not going to be installed
       E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I do to get ros indigo on ubuntu 14.10 installed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196313/installing-ros-indigo-on-ubuntu-14.10-utopic-unicorn/) by [Francesco G](https://answers.ros.org/users/19438/francesco-g/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-10-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

14.10 is not currently supported for Indigo. If you want to figure out why the package manager won't install those packages, you can try installing each package one-at-a-time and you'll get more information as to what the issues are. You could also try building from [source](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source).

EDIT: see [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/196076/building-indigo-on-1410/).

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-02**:
@Francesco G: Please do not use answers to reply to another answer, use comments for that.